# Combine Pandas DataFrames with year columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm struggling to find the most efficient way to combine multiple dataframes with columns that are years and country names for the index. As an example:

GDP.csv

```
     1900  1901  1902
USA  500   600   700
MEX  400   500   600
CAN  300   400   500
```

lifeEx.csv

```
     1900  1901  1902
USA  50   60   70
MEX  40   50   60
CAN  30   40   50
```

I can list the dataframes and use concat to combine them, but this makes it awkward to access each dataframe.

pieces = {'GDP': GDP, 'lifeEx': lifeEx}
result = pd.concat(pieces)

This will show me the value for one dataframe, country, and year. However, I cannot easily list all the data from all countries for a given year.

print(result.loc['GDP','USA'].loc['1900'])

Ideally, I think I want to use groupby() to sort the data by country, year, indicator (GDP, life expectancy, ...), or some combination of these. However, I don't see a clear way to do this.

I also considered iterating over the dataframe to create a year column. However, this is not very efficient. The result would be a file that looks like this, with country and year being the key:

GDP.csv

```
     year  GDP
USA  1900  500
USA  1901  600
USA  1902  700
MEX  1900  400
MEX  1901  500
MEX  1902  600
CAN  1900  300
CAN  1901  400
CAN  1902  500
```

After transforming the data like this, I could combine the dataframes using the country and year as the key. Since the column heading GDP would be unique for each data set, these columns would extend the dataframs rather than being added together.

What is a more elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what you are going for.  Here is some example code.

```
# Import pandas
import pandas as pd

# Load data
df_a = pd.read_csv('gdp.csv')
df_b = pd.read_csv('le.csv')

# Use melt to pull the columns from each df into separate rows tied to the key column.
df_a = df_a.melt(id_vars='country', var_name='year', value_name='gdp')
df_b = df_b.melt(id_vars='country', var_name='year', value_name='le')

# Then it is rather trivial to just merge based on the column names given above.
pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on=['country','year'])

# That would create the following output given your input files (as long as the column naming is correct.

country year gdp le
0   usa 1900 500 50
1   mex 1900 400 40
2   can 1900 300 30
3   usa 1901 600 60
4   mex 1901 500 50
5   can 1901 400 40
6   usa 1902 700 70
7   mex 1902 600 60
8   can 1902 500 50
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to give an exact solution, because it depends on what you eventually want to do with the data after you have merged it. If you only want to sort, like you mentioned, you could just use a pure database

Otherwise, you could look into [Pandas multi-indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html). This will make things clearer when you look at the tables, however I find that I end up wanting to get back into your so-called *melted* form, for things such as plotting and input to neural networks.

Using `groupby` could indeed work, and I find those solution quite elegant. In your case you could just group by year and/or country and then apply the function for your use case.

Given your vernacular, you might be interested to look at the standard database-like functionality of a dataframe, such as [`join` and `merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Answer (score 0):

After asking around, melt() was the most common answer I received. While implementing this using melt() I learned about stack() and that also offered a solution to this problem. Therefore, I setup a couple tests to determine which is the best solution to this problem.

The result appears to be that melt() takes longer to rearrange the data, but offers faster processing for future manipulations of that data. If I was only performing a few operations on the data, stack() may be a better solution.

When combining the dataframes, these were the execution times for melt() and stack() working with the same data set:
Melt: 63ms Stack: 19ms

When retrieving data for a single country from the combined data set, these were the execution times for melt() and stack():
Melt: 6ms Stack: 12ms

As you can see, stack() rearranges the data in 30% of the time required by melt(). However, melt() retrieves the data in 50% of the time required by stack().

It is also important to note that when using melt() I had to call dropna() as an additional step. This removed any rows which contained only NaN for all the columns. With stack() this was done by default.

Comment: Have you tried merge yet?